# How to list one value from more then one column

Tags: oracle

I have a final output table which comes from multiple joins result.

Now assume I have following result

```
Select Product, Price, OwnerA, OwnerB , OwnerC from MyProduct;
```

and only one column have value out of three owner field and I want single column of owner field. so final result need as following
`Select product, price, owner`.

Using Oracle database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT
    Product,
    Price,
    COALESCE(OwnerA, OwnerB, OwnerC) AS Owner
FROM MyProduct
```

The `COALESCE` trick should work here, because it will evaluate inputs from the left to right (i.e. from owner A to B to C), and it will stop with the first non `NULL` value.  Since you are certain that only 1 or 3 owners will be non `NULL`, it should be able to select that non `NULL` value.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Its working when I am using with simple select query of any demo table. but when I apply my actual store procedure code its  returning me this error - 12704. 00000 -  "character set mismatch". Can you give me suggestion ?

Comment: Without seeing your actual query/proc, I can't comment.  It sounds like something having to do with the encoding or column types.  (_Don't_ put your code here as a comment!)

Comment: Just add N'' || before your non-Unicode string constant. - Solved